# Zend Framework 2 routing and setting the defaults 'module', 'controller', 'action' of a route

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

I'm using Zend 2 version 2.2.5 and the Skeleton Application. I added a simple 'Member' module and inside a 'TestController.php'.

What is the best way to write the 'test' route's 'defaults' section?

And later, how do I get the 'module' name from a matched route? I expect there is a simple way in ZF2 to get 'module', 'controller', 'action', but don't know how.

**Option 1:** Produces a 404 Error

```
'defaults' => array(
  'module'     => 'Member',
  'controller' => 'Test',
  'action'     => 'index',
),

A $matchedRoute->getParam('module');     prints 'Member'
A $matchedRoute->getParam('controller'); prints 'Test'
A $matchedRoute->getParam('action');     prints 'index'
```

A 404 error occurred Page not found.
The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class.
Controller: Test(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: Test)

**Option 2:** Works, but 'module' is empty

```
'defaults' => array(
  '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Member\Controller',
  'controller'    => 'Test',
  'action'        => 'index',
),

A $matchedRoute->getParam('module');     prints '' <= EMPTY
A $matchedRoute->getParam('controller'); prints 'Test'
A $matchedRoute->getParam('action');     prints 'index'
```

**Option 3:** Works, but 'module' is empty

```
'defaults' => array(
  'controller' => 'Member\Controller\Test',
  'action'     => 'index',
),

A $matchedRoute->getParam('module');     prints '' <= EMPTY
A $matchedRoute->getParam('controller'); prints 'Member\Controller\Test'
A $matchedRoute->getParam('action');     prints 'index'
```

I try do get the 'module', 'controller', 'action' in onBootstrap() with this code:

```
$sm = $application->getServiceManager();
$router = $sm->get('router');
$request = $sm->get('request');
$matchedRoute = $router->match($request);
print($matchedRoute->getParam('module'));
print($matchedRoute->getParam('controller'));
print($matchedRoute->getParam('action'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You typically add a route for your action like below:

```
'test' => array(
   'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
   'options' => array(
      'route'    => '/test',
      'defaults' => array(
         'module'     => '__NAMESPACE__',
         'controller' => '__NAMESPACE__\Controller\Test',
         'action'     => 'index',
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

To make the `__NAMESPACE__` constant work, add the following line to the beginning of your module's config:

```
namespace Member;
```

#### Extracting Parameters from Route

On route match, the router (top-level route class) returns
some parameters: the "defaults" (parameters listed in the `defaults` section of 
routing configuration) plus any wildcard parameters extracted from URL string.

To retrieve a parameter from the route in your controller's action method, 
you typically use the `Params` controller plugin and its `fromRoute()` method,
which takes two arguments: the name of the parameter to retrieve and the value to
return if the parameter is not present.

The `fromRoute()` method can also be used to retrieve all parameters at once as an array.
To do that, call the `fromRoute()` without arguments, as shown in the example below:

```
// An example action.
public function indexAction() {

  // Get the single 'id' parameter from route.
  $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id', -1);

  // Get all route parameters at once as an array.
  $params = $this->params()->fromRoute();

  //...             
}
```

#### Retrieving the RouteMatch and the Router Object

On route match, the router class internally creates an instance of `Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch` class, 
providing the methods for extracting the matched route name and parameters extracted from route.

To get the `RouteMatch` object from your controller's action method, you can use the following
code:

```
// An example action.
public function indexAction() {

  // Get the RouteMatch object.
  $routeMatch = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch();

  // Get matched route's name.
  $routeName = $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName();

  // Get all route parameters at once as an array.
  $params = $routeMatch->getParams();

  //...             
}
```

For additional information about ZF2 routing, I would recommend reading the [Using Zend Framework 2](http://using-zend-framework-2-book.com/) book.